# ASP.NET MVC 3. How to place validation summary for one form into another form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a small form which needs validation summary, but this validation summary should be definitly placed on another form.

I know, that there is a restriction - validation summary checks only elements in current form, so what am i searching for is some kind of crunch.

Is there any solution which does nt involve writing own validation and hundreds of lines of Javascript?

Comment: There was such an idea to move ValidationSummary on Submit event, but when my method subscribes to this event, method is called before ValidationSummary appears on page - this leads to different but not simpler problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to solve this problem with standart events: before submit event triggered "validate" method Validation Summary is not present on page and callint "validate" stops event dispatching (if you have any errors of cause).

What have i done involves edititng of "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js". Steps:

1) In "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" file in `function onErrors` I added event dispatching:

```
function onErrors(form, validator) {
        // native code
        jQuery("#submitErrorProxy").trigger(jQuery.Event("click")); // my event
    }
```

2) Added hidden input on my form with `id="submitErrorProxy"`

3) added div container on place where Validation Summary should be displayed.

```
<div class="form-line" id="validationSummaryContainer">
     //validation summary should be moved here 
</div>
```

4) Added next Javascipt method

```
    $("#submitErrorProxy").click(function (e) {
                $("#validationSummaryContainer").empty();
                $(".validation-summary-errors").clone(true, true)
                 .appendTo("#validationSummaryContainer");
            });
```

Where `clone(true, true)` - makes copy of chosen element with all its child elements. And `appendTo` used instead of `move` because original validaton summary should be present on original form.

5) Hidden original ValidtionSummary container.

```
<div class="form-line" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's little information you gave about what are these forms and how they are related or why would you need to move that validation information. Plus lets get thing straight : validation summary doesn't check anything it only displays summary of validation errors. You're right though, summary is presented for the parent form only. If you really wan't to move the summary from one form to another you may want to bind to submit() event and using jquery move the .validation-summary-errors element to the other form.